# Bootstrap fixed header width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and can't find any answer to my question.

I am using the AdminLTE bootstrap theme for testing. I want to create a nice website theme with it and I want a fixed width. The fixed width is working but not for the header bar.

I want the header bar and menu to always be fixed.
Because I add the "fixed" class to te body my site is fixed width.
Only the header isn't fixed width. It is only fixed to the screen.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the interior of the header with a `<div class="container"></div>`

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">

            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
              <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <!-- Add the class icon to your logo image or logo icon to add the margining -->
                Testing
            </a>
            </nav>
  </div>
```

You need to remove the margin-left and position fixed from the navbar css as well.

Comment: This is not working. tried it outside the <header> and inside it. Both of them don't work. Setting the container class on the header tag also don't work.

Comment: I wrapped the interior of your header in the inspector and it worked just fine. You should probably move that logo to the inside of the navbar too.

Comment: Can you send me a piece of code? I really can't get it to work